# how to get all elements (visible and invisible)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation, scraper

i stuck in list view where thousands of items but only 20 items show when i scroll down then 20 items more show and so on...

```
<ul class'python'>
    <li> item1 </li>
    <li> item2 </li>
    <li> item3 </li>
     .
     .
     .
    <li> item1000 </li>
</ul>
```

my code also get just show items, i want to get all visible and invisible items through selenium? how can i get that?

```
ul=driver.find_element_by_class('python')
for item in ul.find_elements_by_tag_name("li"): 
    print(item.text)
```

Comment: Could you provide the html page ? Are items all loaded on the page or they are loaded 20 by 20 each time you scroll ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your issue is just to scroll down the webpage, you could do :

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

For a more precise method, if you have the xpath of the next li elemen you want to get to, you can :

```
element=find_element_by_xpath("xpath of the li you are trying to access")
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```